# How to create folders in the DigitalOcean Bucket using Nodejs API?

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean

I am trying to store my data to the DigitalOcean using Nodejs. I can perform list, upload, download operations. But can anyone tell me how to create folders inside the bucket using the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important thing to understand about both Spaces and the S3 API (which Spaces was designed to be interoperable with) is that a "folder" is actually just a "key" with a zero sized "object." Items inside the folder have the folder key as a prefix to their own key. For example, here is a listing of objects in a Space with a folder named `foo` containing a file named `bar`:

```
$ aws s3api --endpoint-url https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com --profile do list-objects --bucket my-bucket
{
    "Contents": [
        {
            "LastModified": "2017-10-17T17:50:50.840Z", 
            "ETag": "\"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e\"", 
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD", 
            "Key": "foo/", 
            "Owner": {
                "DisplayName": "681451698", 
                "ID": "681451698"
            }, 
            "Size": 0
        }, 
        {
            "LastModified": "2017-10-17T17:56:08.583Z", 
            "ETag": "\"8cf8463b34caa8ac871a52d5dd7ad1ef\"", 
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD", 
            "Key": "foo/bar", 
            "Owner": {
                "DisplayName": "681451698", 
                "ID": "681451698"
            }, 
            "Size": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

So you do not need to create a folder at all. You can just upload an object with a key like `path/to/file.ext` If you want an empty "folder" to be visible in the DigitalOcean Spaces' control panel, you can "upload" an empty object with a key ending with a trailing forward slash (`/`). For example:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

const spacesEndpoint = new AWS.Endpoint('sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com'); // Replace with the endpoint for your region.
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    endpoint: spacesEndpoint,
    accessKeyId: 'ACCESS_KEY',
    secretAccessKey: 'SECRET_KEY'
});

var params = {
    Bucket: "my-spaces-bucket",
    Key: "folder/",
};

s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    else     console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I stored my files to Digitalocean. But i am facing a new problem . I have to show the thumbnails of the stored images . Is there a way to do it.?